# convert string value to date format TS

Tags: typescript

I defined my variable as string

```
startedStringDate:string;
```

I want to convert string value to date format. My startedStringDate value is like this

```
startedStringDate='2022/05/01';
```

How could i convert it to date format

Answer (score 0):

I'd you date-fns for this, specifically the parse function: https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/parse

Answer (score 0):

Since your date format uses `/` as seperators, you need to split it before turning it into a Date-Object. You also need to subtract 1 from the month, since  the Date constructor expects a zero-based value (where January = 0, February = 1, March = 2, etc.)

```
const [year, month, day] = str.split('/');

const date = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day);
```